# java интеграция с ip телефонией

Tags: java, spring, ip, телефония

Разрабатываем проект с использованием Spring boot. Требуется реализовать интеграция с IP телефонией, чтобы оператор мог звонить клиенту и наоборот. Какие библиотеки можно использовать для решения этой задачи?